Examples of functions $u:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $\space\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ satisfying interaction condition
I am looking for examples of continuous functions $u:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $\space\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that the following hold for any $x,y,z\in X$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$ (where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set) :
\begin{align*}
&\text{(1) $u$ is unbounded}\newline
& \text{(2) $u(x)\geq u(y) $ implies $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) z)\geq u(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) z)$}\newline
&\text{(3) $\phi$ is a bounded, non-decreasing function}\newline
&\text{(4) $\phi$ is a Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant $\leq 1$.}\newline
&\text{(5) $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)+\phi(u((x))\geq u(x)\iff u(y)+\phi(u(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x))\geq u(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)$}\newline
\end{align*}
What I got so far: If we choose $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u$ to be a (non-constant) affine function, i.e. $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y)=\alpha u(x)+(1-\alpha)u(y)$ , and $\phi=$ constant, then all the properties are fulfilled. However except for this trivial example, I cannot think of any other one.
Also if we wouldn't have condition (5) then (1)-(4) would be easy to fulfill. In this case one could choose $\phi(x)=\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$ for example. A suitable $u$ could be obtained as follows: Consider a (non-constant) affine function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. And consider any increasing, bijective function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. For example $\varphi(x)=x^3$. Then setting $u=\varphi\circ A$ works.
Examples where $u$ is not affine would be great. Or at least where $\phi$ is not trivial.
